# Can I reset my skill tree?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Through The Witcher 3 is it possible at some point of the game to reset my skill tree; in case I made a mistake or want to re-spec? If there is please answer with no spoiler about how to obtain this if spoilers are evident to know, just answer saying yes/no and how far into the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reset your ability points by drinking a Potion of Clearance, which you can buy from some merchants.

One person I know of, who sells the potion, you will come across during the story fairly early on in Velen. The name of the person is:

> Keira Metz. She will sell the potion for 1000 crowns.

Comment: What I was looking for! Thank you <3